# Angular JS apply uppercase filter to boolean value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have an angular 1.4.12 binding:

```
{{ mob.mobDataSettings[7].value | uppercase }}
```

where the first part is a boolean from a json file which is of course either true or false.

however, in the rendered HTML it is not being uppercased (i.e. `TRUE`), it's printing as `true`.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a boolean, even if it could work, it's bad practise to try to apply a filter made for strings.
I suggest you go with `{{ mob.mobDataSettings[7].value ? "TRUE" : "FALSE" }}`

Comment: Clever solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to cast to string before filter:

```
{{ '' + mob.mobDataSettings[7].value | uppercase }}
```

Answer (score 0):

{{ mob.mobDataSettings[7].value.toString() | uppercase }}

or could you just do

{{ mob.mobDataSettings[7].value.toString().toUpper()  }}